# How can I enlarge the character in Eclipse\Aptana?

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana

Can I enlarge the text size (of the code and in the menu\package explorer) in Eclipse?

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> 'Colors and Fonts' and change appropriate fonts or increase the system font.